# JPA - Attempt to create NamedEntityGraph to avoid multiple selects (parent with OneToOne and OneToMany children)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have been out of practice with JPA for years and I am now retrying things (using Spring boot/Hibernate)

I have the following (Kotlin)

```
@NamedEntityGraphs(*[
    NamedEntityGraph(
            name = "user-role",
            attributeNodes = [
                NamedAttributeNode("name") ,
                NamedAttributeNode("userRoles", subgraph = "roleproperties")] ,
            subgraphs = [
                NamedSubgraph (name="roleproperties", attributeNodes = [NamedAttributeNode("roleType")])]
    )
])

@Entity
@Table(name = "[user]")
class UserEntity(
        @Id  @Column(name="id")
        val id: UUID,
        val name: String,
        val email: String,
        @OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY) @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
        val userRoles: Set<UserRoleEntity> ,
        @OneToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, optional = true ) @JoinColumn(name="id")
        val userProperties: UserPropertiesEntity
) { }

...

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
class UserRoleEntity(
        @Id
        val id: UUID,
        val roleType: String
)
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_properties")
class UserPropertiesEntity(
    @Id
    val userId: UUID,
    val updatedBy: UUID?,
    val updatedAt: Timestamp?,
    val properties: String?
    ) {}



...
```

When querying using the 'user-role' graph, and looking at the SQL, 2 statements are executed
The first joins user with user_role table (which is what I would expect)
The second query however is a select on the user_properties table. I don't understand why this second select is there. The idea is that nothing is needed from the user_properties table.

The user-role graph is used as follows

```
val graph = entityManager.getEntityGraph("user-properties")
val properties: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
properties["javax.persistence.fetchgraph"] = graph
val ue = entityManager.find(UserEntity::class.java, UUID.fromString(id), properties)
```

All tips welcomed!

Tx

Peter

Answer (score 1):

The second query for fetching the `user_properties` is needed due to the fact that `hibernate` needs to know whether it should place a null or a proxy for the `one-to-one` relation of `UserEntity` for `UserPropertiesEntity` field.

To say in other words; even if you specified the relation as `lazy`, there is no way hibernate would know whether the relation is null or it should put a proxy for the corresponding `userProperties` field, hence it needs to execute the second query to fetch the user properties. In other words; hibernate is not able to respect the fetch strategy `FetchType.LAZY` for `one-to-one` relation.

You can look at the following [post](https://medium.com/monstar-lab-bangladesh-engineering/jpa-hibernate-bidirectional-lazy-loading-done-right-65eda6426d64) if you really want to make the association truely lazy.

Comment: Thanks! The referenced post is very instructive as well

Comment: So,with bytecode enhancement and LazyToOne annotation,the extra select on user_properties is gone.But,when trying an entitygraph that should fetch user and user_properties in one select it fails. 
There is a select on user table only and then an exception `"org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: Unable to perform requested lazy initialization [com.datylon.gql2.model.UserEntity.userProperties] - no session and settings disallow loading outside the Session"`. I guess I am back at the start

Comment: I have no experience with entity graphs and how they work. sorry for that. as a matter of fact I generally prefer to leave `one-to-one` relations as eager and sometimes fetch them with fetch join directly instead of letting hibernate do a second query. somebody with more experience on entity graphs should help further I hope.